# What is the order of execution? JQuery: $(document).ready(function () { }); $(window).on('load', function () { })

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the **order of execution** for the below sample code? Will `$(window).on('load', function () { })` be executed before completing `$(document).ready(function () { });`.

I need to change all the text field values to uppercase after loading values form server through AJAX call. This page has more than twenty fields.

```
//Sample Code
$(window).on('load', function () {
      //Some Code... to change all text field values to uppercase

      alert("Window Loaded");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Some Code....

    $.ajax({
        url: "TestLoadOne",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('async false Ajax');
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "TestLoadOne",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('async false Ajax');
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "TestLoadOne",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('async false Ajax');
        }
    });

    alert("Document Loaded");
});

//C# Code.
public string TestLoadOne()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40000);
    return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready#:~:text=ready()%20is%20a%20jQuery%20event%20which%20occurs%20when%20the,images%20on%20the%20page%20loaded.&text=onload%20is%20a%20pure%20javascript,is%20a%20method%20in%20jQuery.)s  your question.

Comment: I am concerning about the AJAX calls inside document.ready. Will $(window).on("load", function(){}); wait for AJAX call (inside document.ready) to complete?

Comment: No, the window onload event is not dependent on AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1):

Because your AJAX calls are asynchronous, there isn't really telling in what order they will finish. What we do know is that the calls will be fired off inside `document.ready` before `window.onLoad` is called ([see for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)). Ideally you should write your callbacks such that their order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

> Will $(window).on('load', function () { }) be executed before
>   completing $(document).ready(function () { });.

The answer is "Yes".

`$(window).on('load', function () { })` will be executed **AFTER** `$(document).ready(function () { })`

However, since there are asynchronous operations are involved here (AJAX), they will be completed after `$(window).on('load', function () { })` gets executed.

Even inside `$(document).ready(function () { })`

`alert("Document Loaded");` will execute before the `AJAX` request is processed.

Let's mimic this:

```js
function A(){ //Similar to document.ready

setTimeout(()=>{
 alert("hello from setTimeout") //similar to Ajax request
}, 0)

 alert("hello from A")
}

function B(){

alert("Hello from B") //Similar to window.load
}

function C(){ //Any other function in the script executing after window.load

  alert("Hello from C") 
}


A();
B();
C()
```

You notice that `setTimeout` gets executed after all of these methods execution get finished.

Answer (score 1):

it depends, for your case you are using `$.ajax`, if you set the `async` to false, it will wait for the `$.ajax` until it finishes and return a response, but if you set it to true it will not wait:

**`async: false,`:**

```js
//Sample Code
$(window).on('load', function () {
      //Some Code... to change all text field values to uppercase
      alert("Window Loaded");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Document Loaded");
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('async false Ajax');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**`async: true,`:**

```js
//Sample Code
$(window).on('load', function () {
      //Some Code... to change all text field values to uppercase
      alert("Window Loaded");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Document Loaded");
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('async true Ajax');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```